# Network Manager unexpectedly disconnecting from wireless

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, intel-wireless

`lspci`:

```
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Policy set 'ECURB' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> DNS: starting dnsmasq...
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <error> [1413740997.702896] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:396] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Oct 19 13:49:58 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
Oct 19 13:49:58 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> dnsmasq appeared on DBus: :1.34
Oct 19 13:49:58 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Oct 19 13:50:13 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Oct 19 13:50:13 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Oct 19 13:50:13 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Oct 19 13:50:13 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Oct 19 13:53:29 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason -4)
Oct 19 13:53:29 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 19 13:53:29 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 19 13:53:33 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 19 13:53:33 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 19 13:53:34 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 19 13:53:37 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 19 13:53:38 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 19 13:53:39 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 19 13:53:42 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 19 13:53:42 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> (wlan0): link timed out.
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [100 120 53]
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'ECURB'
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1645
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Oct 19 13:53:48 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    13049  1 
ccm                    17773  1 
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  8 
snd_hda_codec_analog    15049  1 
hid_generic            12548  0 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
usbhid                 52659  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            62209  0 
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             143109  0 
kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
pcmcia                 62299  0 
joydev                 17381  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
arc4                   12608  2 
lpc_ich                21080  0 
yenta_socket           41027  0 
pcmcia_rsrc            18407  1 yenta_socket
pcmcia_core            23592  3 pcmcia,pcmcia_rsrc,yenta_socket
iwl3945                73259  0 
iwlegacy              100569  1 iwl3945
mac80211              630653  2 iwl3945,iwlegacy
cfg80211              484040  3 iwl3945,iwlegacy,mac80211
snd_hda_intel          56451  6 
snd_hda_codec         192906  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_analog
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
i915                  783805  3 
btusb                  32412  0 
drm_kms_helper         53081  1 i915
bluetooth             391136  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
drm                   303102  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
thinkpad_acpi          81013  0 
nvram                  14411  1 thinkpad_acpi
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
wmi                    19177  0 
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69322  22 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12680  1 snd
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
video                  19476  1 i915
psmouse               106678  0 
firewire_ohci          40409  0 
firewire_core          68769  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
e1000e                254433  0 
ptp                    18933  1 e1000e
pps_core               19382  1 ptp
```

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82566MM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:1c:25:b6:d6:fd
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.3-0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:fe000000-fe01ffff memory:fe025000-fe025fff ioport:1840(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1f:3c:55:a7:e6
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.13.0-36-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 ip=192.168.0.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:47 memory:df3ff000-df3fffff
```

`Network Manager activity form syslog`:

```
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Policy set 'ECURB' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> DNS: starting dnsmasq...
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <error> [1413740997.702896] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:396] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Oct 19 13:49:57 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Oct 19 13:49:58 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
Oct 19 13:49:58 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> dnsmasq appeared on DBus: :1.34
Oct 19 13:49:58 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Oct 19 13:50:13 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Oct 19 13:50:13 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Oct 19 13:50:13 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Oct 19 13:50:13 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Oct 19 13:53:29 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason -4)
Oct 19 13:53:29 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 19 13:53:29 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 19 13:53:33 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 19 13:53:33 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 19 13:53:34 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 19 13:53:37 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 19 13:53:38 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 19 13:53:39 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 19 13:53:42 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 19 13:53:42 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> (wlan0): link timed out.
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [100 120 53]
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'ECURB'
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1645
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Oct 19 13:53:45 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Oct 19 13:53:48 linux NetworkManager[850]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```

Comment: Try using the instructions in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680711/159028 to add debug logging for more information.